# How do I SELECT a column of dates and use that to drive a second SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to build a MYSQL VERSION 5.6.15 query that will allow me to do a SELECT statement that returns a column of answers and then use that column to build the next SELECT statement.

I'm new to mySQL and have tried a bunch of ideas but so far have failed. I'm sure that the answer must be simple but I've given on on figuring it out myself. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the simplest set of data that I could use to demonstrate my dilemma:

```
    order_date             quantity
    '2014-01-01 00:00:00', '27'
    '2014-01-02 00:00:00', '13'
    '2014-01-03 00:00:00', '42'
    '2014-01-04 00:00:00', '30'
    '2014-01-05 00:00:00', '5'
    '2014-01-06 00:00:00', '50'
    '2014-01-07 00:00:00', '2'
    '2014-01-08 00:00:00', '10'
    '2014-01-09 00:00:00', '40'
    '2014-01-10 00:00:00', '4'
    '2014-01-11 00:00:00', '32'
    '2014-01-13 00:00:00', '17'
    '2014-01-15 00:00:00', '54'
    '2014-01-17 00:00:00', '14'
    '2014-01-20 00:00:00', '37'
    '2014-01-22 00:00:00', '12'
```

My first query would be something like this:

```
SELECT order_date, quantity 
FROM orders
WHERE quantity >35
```

So, I'd get this back:

```
    order_date             quantity
    '2014-01-03 00:00:00', '42'
    '2014-01-06 00:00:00', '50'
    '2014-01-09 00:00:00', '40'
    '2014-01-15 00:00:00', '54'
    '2014-01-20 00:00:00', '37'
```

Now, the next query I'd want would be to select the `order_date` and `quantity` for the NEXT ENTRY of each of the above from the `order_date` column.

**NOTE:** The dates aren't always going to be consecutive so an INTERVAL +1 won't always be relevant.

So, the second query would return the following rows:

```
    order_date             quantity
    '2014-01-04 00:00:00', '30'
    '2014-01-07 00:00:00', '2'
    '2014-01-10 00:00:00', '4'
    '2014-01-17 00:00:00', '14'
    '2014-01-22 00:00:00', '12'
```

Ideally, I could put them all together with the first query, sorted by date. I know it's gotta be some kind of `join` or `IN` statement but so far this has eluded me. So, the ultimate solution would return this:

```
    order_date             quantity
    '2014-01-03 00:00:00', '42'
    '2014-01-04 00:00:00', '30'
    '2014-01-06 00:00:00', '50'
    '2014-01-07 00:00:00', '2'
    '2014-01-09 00:00:00', '40'
    '2014-01-10 00:00:00', '4'
    '2014-01-15 00:00:00', '54'
    '2014-01-17 00:00:00', '14'
    '2014-01-20 00:00:00', '37'
    '2014-01-22 00:00:00', '12'
```

Comment: so you want the second select to be a selection of the quantity from the next day?

Comment: @JohnRuddell: OP had a note in is posting. *NOTE: The dates aren't always going to be consecutive so an INTERVAL +1 won't always be relevant.*

Comment: I got that... i meant the next date in the database --- like if its a day or two days or three.. the next date in the database

Comment: Yep, it would be the next date in the database

Comment: do you have an ID field in the table as well?

Comment: I don't, but if that would help, I'd be happy to do so. I just need to make sure that it would stay consistent and it would be good if the ID could be somehow generated automatically based on date when the data was imported into the DB.

Comment: no problem.. i did it differently... generally though its good to have an ID field.. incase you ever have more tables you want to join, as well as indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick.. its not the best way to build a query as it can run slowly with a really large table... but this should do what you want... see fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7a53/10

```
SELECT 
  order_date as o_date, 
  quantity,
  (SELECT order_date FROM orders WHERE order_date > o_date LIMIT 1) as next_date,
  (SELECT quantity FROM orders WHERE order_date > o_date LIMIT 1) as next_quantity
FROM orders
where quantity > 35
```

Comment: check out the fiddle link.. i build the schema in there   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7a53/10

Comment: Thanks John! Yep, the fiddle link was great and I am seeing a result that is not an error in MYSQL Workbench. I need to dig in and fully understand what you did here but it looks like what I'm looking for. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: one thing. do you want to see the stuff in 4 columns? or just 2?

Comment: If it could be in just 2 columns, that would be best, that's why I was thinking some sort of join may need to be involved

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7a53/13 --- then that is what you want... its a bit hefty.. but you have to union two selects that are selecting the same stuff.. then select everything from that to order the date by ascending so its in the correct order ---- if you want to know what I did you need to run each query separately and see what im doing in each one... and then on the first inside select... I do where the date is > the current date you are on (in that row) `limit 1` so that it just gets the first next one.

Comment: dont forget to +1 :D ---- when you can that is :)

Comment: Yep, I will do so, when they let me. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT order_date, quantity,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY order_date) AS RowNumber
    FROM Orders 
),
FilteredOrders AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OrderedOrders 
    WHERE quantity>35
)

SELECT OrderedOrders.order_date, OrderedOrders.quantity  
FROM OrderedOrders INNER JOIN FilteredOrders 
ON OrderedOrders.RowNumber=FilteredOrders.RowNumber 
OR OrderedOrders.RowNumber=FilteredOrders.RowNumber+1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Reza, it gave me a few other things to think about in doing not just this query but a few others I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach

```
-- initial filter
select filter.date, filter.quantity
  from data filter
  where filter.quantity>35
union -- together with set of "next" values
select next.date, next.quantity
from data next, ( -- join table with filtered values
  select q1.date
  from data q1
  where q1.quantity>35) filtered
where next.date = ( -- where the date is just after the date in the filtered row set
  select min(q2.date)
  from data q2
  where q2.date>filtered.date)
order by 1 -- and get the order as you wish
```

It wasn't intuitive, so was fun to work out. BTW watch out if you have duplicate dates. There's an [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34939/20).

Comment: Thanks for the answer wwkudu, it gave me a few other things to think about in doing not just this query but a few others I'm working on.